# Does shebang overwrite the python interpreter path

Tags: python

I’m wondering if shebang is specified in the python script, does it overwrite the caller?

For example, let’s say I have a test.py,

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
print(“hello world”)
```

And then I call it this way:
/usr/bin/python2 test.py

Which python version will call the hello world print fiction?

Comment: The shebang is seen only by the shell executing the file; the Python interpreter ignores it as it is a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It is only used if you make your python file executable and  run directly

```
./test.py
```

As it is being read and used by the shell attempting to run that file. By doing

```
/usr/bin/python2 test.py
```

you in fact run `/usr/bin/python2` interpreter, which is given `test.py` as argument. And python interpreter ignores shebang as this is just python comment line syntax.

Comment: Looks like this answer does not apply on my side: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78080274/using-python-interpreter-explicitely-does-not-ignore-shebang