# Using python interpreter explicitely does not ignore shebang

Tags: python, python-3.x, shebang

I have read [Does shebang overwrite the python interpreter path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64120768/does-shebang-overwrite-the-python-interpreter-path), and it seems the given answer does not apply to me.

Some context: I am on Windows using `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe` and having two python installations as you can see:

```
$ py --version
Python 3.10.11

$ which py
/c/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Launcher/py

$ python3 --version
Python 3.9.10

$ which python3
/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/python3
```

Have created a dummy python file `shebang.py` to print out the python version used

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
print(sys. version)
```

```
$ py shebang.py 
3.9.10 (heads/mingw-v3.9.10-dirty:12d1cb5b7c, Dec  9 2022, 03:24:49)  [GCC UCRT 12.2.0 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Looks like `python3` is used and not `py`. Same behaviour if I call `./shebang.py` .

How can I make sure `py` is used rather?

edit (@wRAR comment):

When I remove the shebang line from `shebang.py` I indeed can use `py`

```
$ py shebang.py 
3.10.11 (tags/v3.10.11:7d4cc5a, Apr  5 2023, 00:38:17) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Comment: If you remove the shebang is the behavior the same?

Comment: It is not it is using `py` let me add this point

Comment: What does `py -0p` print for you? I have 4 installs and it chooses the newest/default.

Comment: `py -0p` gives me this:
```-V:3.10 *        C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *are* using `py`. It's a Python interpreter selector, not Python 3.10. Shebang handling is most of `py`'s job.

If you want to override the shebang, `py` supports command-line flags to specify a Python version. For example,

```
py -3.10 shebang.py
```

will run `shebang.py` with Python 3.10, regardless of what any shebang line in the script might say.

Answer (score 2):

`py` is not a Python interpreter, it's the [Windows Python launcher](https://peps.python.org/pep-0397/), thus the link you provide does not apply.

The Windows launcher `py` supports the shebang syntax, as specified in [PEP 397](https://peps.python.org/pep-0397/#shebang-line-parsing):

> The launcher supports the syntax of shebang lines as described in [1], including all restrictions listed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Are there any ways to make sure `py` is used and ignore the shebang?

Comment: @coincoin Why do you need the shebang?

Comment: Other coworkers are using this file on other platforms like Linux and they run the script directly without the interpreter. 
We have thought about having another script to wrap this and we were wondering if there could be a more elegant way.

Comment: @coincoin You should work in virtual environment, then you can simply call `python` and this will call the interpreter from your environment. Any reason you would need to call the system interpreter(s) directly?

Comment: @coincoin: `py` *is* being used.

Comment: `py` is not Python 3.10. It's a Python interpreter selector. If you want to use Python 3.10 instead of using `py`'s default interpreter selection logic, you *might* be able to override the shebang with `py -3.10 yourscript` - I'm not sure whether flags like `-3.10` only work interactively, or if you can use them with a script, but I *think* they should work with a script too.

Comment: @user2357112 this is lovely `py -3.10` indeed works for me. You can make an answer if you want as it works for me and I will approve it thanks!